# Named/typed parameters using variadic templates

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm playing around a bit with named/typed parameters using variadic templates, and have the following class:

```
class audio_source_t
{
public:

    virtual ~audio_source_t()
    {
    }

    template<typename T...>
    void receive(const T&... args)
    {
        auto tuple = std::tie(args...);

        receive_impl(std::get<boost::optional<sample_rate_t>>(tuple),
                     std::get<boost::optional<nb_channels_t>>(tuple));                   
    }

private:

    virtual void receive(audio_frame_t& destination,
                         const boost::optional<sample_rate_t>& sample_rate_hint = nullptr,
                         const boost::optional<nb_channels_t>& nb_channels_hint = nullptr) const;
};
```

Where the parameters types are defined as:

```
template<typename T>
class explicit_class
{
public:
    explicit sample_rate_t(T value)
        : value_(value)
    {
    }

    explicit operator T()
    {
        return value_;
    }

private:
    T value_;
};

class sample_rate_t : public explicit_class<int>{};
class nb_channels_t : public explicit_class<int>{};
```

So far so good, now I can use the class as follows:

```
audio_source.receive(boost::optional<sample_rate_t>(48000),
                     boost::optional<nb_channels_t >(2));

audio_source.receive(boost::optional<nb_channels_t>(2), 
                     boost::optional<sample_rate_t>(48000));
```

Parameter order doesn't matter and it is explicit, great.

However, it would be even better if optional parameters, were actually optional and I wouldn't need to mention `boost::optional` for specified parameters, e.g.

```
audio_source.receive(sample_rate_t(48000), 
                     nb_channels_t(2));

audio_source.receive(nb_channels_t(2), 
                     sample_rate_t(48000));

audio_source.receive(sample_rate_t(48000));

audio_source.receive(nb_channels_t(2));
```

I know that I could just simply create all the possible overloads, however when I get up to +3 parameters, that quickly turn impractical.

Any suggestions as to how to achieve this improvement?

Basically what I need is something like:

```
get_or_nullptr_t<sample_rate_t>(tuple)
```

Which during compile time can decide whether the tuple contains the type and otherwise return `std::nullptr_t()`.

Comment: Boost has a named parameters library if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @chris: It does, and I'm sorry to say that in my opinion it results in unreadable code.

Comment: Not saying I think I can do better. But I at least want to try as an exercise.

Comment: I know what you mean. It's still pretty fun to do things like this. This is coming from the one who got bored this morning and started making `str =~ (s/"cat"/"dog"/g);` syntax that worked.